# show related count for grouped column

Tags: php

I am having following query

```
select count(*) as cnt, status_code from table1 group by status_code
```

What i need is to get the count for the related status_code in php

I have a switch statement

```
function get_status()
{
    switch(n)
        {
            case 1:
            $status = 'Test';
            break;
            case 2:
            ....
        }

}
```

I want the output something like this

Status             Count

1. Test             5
2. Population       10

How can i achieve it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to query your DB as usual and than use result of that query like

```
foreach ($result as $row){
  echo $row['status_code'].' '.$row['cnt'];
}
```

note, that your result array can be differ from that i talking about. it depends on what you exactly query your DB

Answer (score 0):

See my example script below, you can understand it    :

```
<?php
$qr_count = mysql_query("select count(*) as cnt, status_code from table1 group by status_code");

while($fa_count = mysql_fetch_array($qr_count)) {
    $status_code = $fa_count['status_code'];
    $count = $fa_count['cnt'];
    $arr = array(1 => 'Test', 2=> 'Population', 3=> 'Some');
    echo $arr[$status_code] .': '.$count .'<br />';
}
```